Windows can’t find Python3.12 wheel.exe.deleteme
python -m pip install -U pip --user
After running this command shows the warning
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python312\\Scripts\\wheel.exe' -> 'C:\\Python312\\Scripts\\wheel.exe.deleteme'

Why am I getting this error?

"Answer for Why I'm getting that": do you only want to know why it didn't work or do you also want to fix the issue?
According to the error message, the installation didn't work because it couldn't find C:\Python312\Scripts\wheel.exe.deleteme
According to Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] No such file or directory, to fix this, try running this command as an administrator (open command prompt -> run as administrator)
